# How to extract a lot of env variable in terms of array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, dotenv

I have more than 10 API account and keys stored in `.env`

My .env:

```
API_ACCOUNT_1="11111"
API_SECRET_1="12121"

API_ACCOUNT_2="22222"
API_SECRET_2="232323"

API_ACCOUNT_3="33333"
API_SECRET_3="343434"

API_ACCOUNT_4="44444"
API_SECRET_4="454545"
...
```

What I want to achieve but not working:

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv"

dotenv.config()

let accountInfo = []

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++){
    // it is not the correct syntax
    accountInfo.push([process.env.`'API_ACCOUNT_${i}'`, process.env.`'API_SECRET_${i}'`])  
}
```

Comment: Anything inside "``" is considered a part of the string. You do not need to add `'` like this. try : process.env.`API_ACCOUNT_${i}`

Comment: I got `SyntaxError: Unexpected template string` by simply using : process.env.`API_ACCOUNT_1` . @TusharShahi

Comment: please try

process.env[`API_ACCOUNT_${i}`]

Comment: My bad it got formatted -> "process.env.(BACKTICK)API_ACCOUNT_${i}(BACKTICK)

Comment: Thanks, it works, may I ask what kind of syntax is it? @NicklausBrain

Comment: Also see: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: I tried process.env./`API_ACCOUNT_1`/, but getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '/'`.

Comment: @forbidden
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let accountInfo = []

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++){
    accountInfo.push([process.env[`API_ACCOUNT_${i}`], process.env[`API_SECRET_${i}`]])  
}
```

Please try